# Excel VBA Compile Error with String Array

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a problem with VBA in Excel. My goal was to have a Userform with several comboboxes, with all the same content, which is extracted from a Excel-chart.
I used the command

> ComboBox.Rowsource = "A1:A10"

And that for every combobox i had in my userform. then i realized it was much code, because i wrote this command for every box again. So i tried out to use a string array, lets call it "A", with the content "Combobox1" and "Combobox2" and so on.
But when i tried to use this in the code -

> for i = 1 to 10
>
> A(i-1).rowsource = "A1:A10"
>
> next

- i got the warning: Compile Error: Invalide qualifier

What is my mistake?

Many Thanks for any help, D.K.

Comment: To find out why you get the `compile error` we will need to see the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `List` property of the `ComboBox` to fill your combo-box with values from a Range (column):

```
ComboBox.List = Range("A1:A10").Value
```

To populate a `ComboBox` with values from `A` array, you can use the code below:

```
Dim A() As Variant

A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) '<-- populate array (for example)
ComboBox.List = A '<-- populate combo-box with array values
```

---

To populate `A` array with values from a `Range`, and later on populate your `ComboBox` from that `A` array, use the code below:

```
Dim A() As Variant

A = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A10"))  '<-- populate array from Range("A1:A10")
ComboBox.List = A '<-- populate combo-box with array values
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `string array` you could use `VBA.Collection` to store the comboboxes of the Form. This might be more easy then `array`.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim A As Collection
Set A = New VBA.Collection

' One way of adding specific comboboxes to the collection
A.Add Me.ComboBox1, Me.ComboBox1.Name
A.Add Me.ComboBox2, Me.ComboBox2.Name
A.Add Me.ComboBox3, Me.ComboBox3.Name
' and so on for all combo boxes on the form

Set A = New VBA.Collection

' Another way would be to loop through the controls and filter the comboboxes out
Dim c As MSForms.control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        A.Add c, c.Name
    End If
Next c

For i = 1 To A.Count
    A(i).RowSource = "A1:A10"
Next
```